# Проблема с onActivityResult при смене ориентации

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 2 activity (***MainActivity*** i ***SecondActivity***) из ***MainActivity*** через `startActivityForResult()` я запускаю ***SecondActivity*** которое должно вернуть некоторою информацию. Проблема в следующем: если я например запускаю ***SecondActivity*** из ***MainActivity*** при вертикальной ориентации экрана и потом в ***SecondActivity*** меняю ориентацию на альбомную и возвращаюсь через кнопку **back** обратно, то информация не передается( У ***MainActivity*** не вызывается метод `onActivityResult()` ). Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему. 
* Если возвращаться в ***MainActivity*** из ***SecondActivity*** не меняя ориентации, то все работает нормально.
Вот метод SecondActivity который вызывается в `onCreate()`

```
private void setAnswerShown(boolean isAnswerShown) {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    }
```

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Создайте [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Если можно, то выложите код, где отправляете результат.

Comment: @qwerty123 , добавил

Comment: Используйте http://square.github.io/otto/. Подпишитесь в первой активити. Из второй, когда нужно вызывайте эвент и передавайте там все, что Вам необходимо, а в первой активити обрабатывайте переданную инфу, как нужно. Или используйте любую другую bus lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так происходит, потому что при смене ориентации по умолчанию активити пересоздается. Добавьте в манифест для ваших активити `configChanges`. Только это подойдет, если вы используете один и тот же layout.xml для landscape и portrait orientation

```
<activity android:name=".OursActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

**Update** 
Попробуйте вызвать `setAnswerShown` в `onBackPressed` и добавьте после `setResult finish();`

Comment: У меня 2 разных layout-a

Comment: странно, у меня работает, создал две активити, для каждой ориентации одтельные layout, и onActivityResult вызывается

Comment: все, спасибо, решил проблему. Я просто в configChanges добавил только orientation, теперь добавил еще screenSize и все заработало.Если вам не сложно, то могли бы еще пояснить почему без screenSize оно не работало ?

Comment: андроид думает, что при смене ориентации еще и размер экрана меняется т. е. ширина и высота теперь у него другая и тоже пересоздает активити, но фишка в том, что у меня и без этих флагов все заработало))

Comment: еще одна проблема, теперь при при смене ориентации не меняется layout. Я так понял что с двумя layout-ами сделать не получится

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант сделать `boolean isAnswerShown` полем класса и переопределить `onBackPressed`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: у меня метод setAnswerShown вызывается только при нажатии на кнопку.